# Can I declaritively create a collection of strings?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm just mucking about with some wpf stuff and I want to quickly create a list of strings that I can use as a resource.  Can i create a list decoratively in xmal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, use Array extension 
 [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752340.aspx) 
 [link text](http://www.wpfwiki.com/Default.aspx?Page=WPF%20Q16.1&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)